# Using Java Date utils vs SQL DATEADD()

Tags: java, sql-server

Is there a way to add number of days to a date using java Date apis, vs hitting the database?

The date input is off format: `yyyy-MM-dd`, `MM/dd/yyyy`

Here is my current code:

```
public String AddToDate(String holdDate, int holdDays)
{
        try
        {
            Database db = new Database();

            String sQuery = "SELECT DATEADD(dd,?,?) AS NewDate";

            Object[] param = new Object[2];
            param[0] = holdDays;
            param[1] = holdDate;

            db.queryPS(sQuery, param);

            if ( db.getRow() )
            {
                return db.getField("NewDate");
            }
            else
                return "";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a conceptual problem with using the database date functions.  What is wrong with your current code, and which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: use `Calendar.add`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but this is what I have so far:

```
 public String AddToDate(String holdDate, int holdDays)
    {
        try
        {
            String newDate = "";
            SimpleDateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date date1 = inFormatter.parse(holdDate);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date1);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, holdDays);  // number of days to add
            newDate = (inFormatter.format(cal.getTime()));

            return newDate;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```